# ExpressionEngine - PHP in template, Print something if entry has certain field value?

Tags: expressionengine

I have a template that is used for entries. The entries have a field that will always have 1 of 2 values. Can I write some PHP to show something different depending on the field value?

Ive tried the following but it gives me a PHP error:

```
<?php if($my_field == 'value1') { ?>
   <h3>Value 1</h3>
   <?php } else { ?>
   <h3>Value 2</h3>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use PHP.

```
{if my_field == 'foo'}
    Value 1
{if:else}
    Value 2
{/if}
```

If you're planning on doing any EE tag processing within those conditionals, you shouldn't use the if:else syntax, as with it, the content between the conditionals will *always* be parsed, but just not displayed, which needlessly uses server resources and increases load time.

So in that case, use simple conditionals instead:

```
{if my_field == 'foo'}
    Value 1
{/if}
{if my_field == 'bar'}
    Value 2
{/if}
```

See: http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html

Comment: Its not working for me but ive been looking at the EE site and forums and I know if should. Any idea how to debug this? Thanks

Comment: Start by outputting the value of the variable in the template (`{my_field}`), so you can make sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: In my template, using {job_type} only works if its in channel tags, where it prints 'value1' and 'value2' multiple times (for each of the entries).

Comment: If its not in channel tags, then the text '{job_type}' is shown on the page instead of any results.

Comment: Yes, the code I posted absolutely needs to be within the channel:entries tags.

Comment: OK, but its printing all the results, its not filtering by the field value of the entry's page. Thanks

Comment: What kind of field is `my_field`? And be sure it's either using no quotes or braces (`{if my_field}`) or *both* quotes and braces (`{if "{my_field}"}`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExpressionEngine's [Conditional Global Variables](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html) to display your content, without having to use PHP in your templates.

Rewriting your example using native ExpressionEngine's *Simple Conditional tags* would result in the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" dynamic="off"}
    {if "my_field" == "value1"}
        Value 1
    {/if}

    {if "my_field" == "value2"}
        Value 2
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You can use [simple or complex conditionals](http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/simple-vs-complex-conditionals-in-expressionengine-templates) anywhere in your templates, with the former being less resource expensive, but [ExpressionEngine's Parse Order](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf) *(PDF, 32 KB)* may affect how they're evaluated and replaced.

In most cases, you'll need to ensure your custom fields and conditionals are within the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag loop for the values to be properly output and tested when the page is being built.

Comment: Your code returns the text 'Value 1' and 'Value 2' for every entry. It doesn't take into account what the value for the field is for the piece of content who's page your on. Thanks

Comment: I forgot to surround the custom field `my_field` with quotes. It should properly evaluate now.

Comment: Now I don't get any result at all on the page :(

Comment: You may need to modify the parameters in your `exp:channel:entries` to suit your content. The code snippet I posted wasn't a complete, working example; rather it's a starting point for showing how to use native EE simple conditionals.

Comment: Ive had a look at the documentation and I cant find any parameters that I can use. Im surprised as I would have thought this to be quite standard stuff.

Comment: Can you update your question with a more complete code sample? It's probably an easy fix if we can see more of what you're trying to do :)

Comment: On my site I have job pages. Every job is either Contract or Permanent, which is specified by a text field. When your on a Permanent job page I need a listing of the other Permanent jobs. When your on a Contact job page I need a listing of the other Contract jobs.

Comment: Initially I tried to pass the value of the field (from the job who's page your on) as a search parameter in the channel tags. However I couldn't get this working. I thought it would be simpler to have 2 channel tags, one for Contact and one for Permanent, and use conditional statements to only show the relevant one. Is that sufficient detail or would some more code still be helpful? I tried to simplify the code I posted for clarity.

Comment: We really do need a complete copy of the actual code you're trying to use. try pasting it on jsfiddle.net.